# pgfplot discrete integers on axis

Tags: pgfplots

With pgfplot when plotting data over a small range of integers, some integers are shown multiple times to "fill" the horizontal axis. I wonder if it is possible to show only discrete integers. Since I automate the generation of figures I don't want to set the ticks manually.

Heres my example code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{values.csv}
    int,value
    1, 3.2
    2, 6.5
    4, 6.8
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Integers},
    ylabel={Value},
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        precision=0,
    },
    ]
    \addplot table [x=int, y=value, col sep=comma] {values.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286608/pgfplot-dateplot-discrete-dates-on-axis????

Comment: Yes it is, but this one is more simple? I was really not sure to change the question of ask a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are *not* duplicated ticks.  If you we use `precision=1` the result is

[image]

So, those were the intermediate values and their value was being truncated since you had set `precision=0`.

One way to automate this is to adapt the solution from [How to prevent rounded and duplicated tick labels in pgfplots with fixed precision?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248924/how-to-prevent-rounded-and-duplicated-tick-labels-in-pgfplots-with-fixed-precisi) and suppress the ticks if their value is not an integer.  This yeilds the desired result:

[image]

### Related Question:

- [pgfplot dateplot discrete dates on axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286608/pgfplot-dateplot-discrete-dates-on-axis)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{values.csv}
    int,value
    1, 3.2
    2, 6.5
    4, 6.8
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    xlabel={Integers},
    ylabel={Value},
    xticklabel={%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\IntegerTick}{\tick}%
        \pgfmathprintnumberto[verbatim,fixed,precision=3]{\tick}\tickAdjusted%
        \pgfmathparse{\IntegerTick == \tickAdjusted ? 1: 0}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax$\IntegerTick$\else\fi%
    },  
    ]
    \addplot table [x=int, y=value, col sep=comma] {values.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but if I change the integers to, for example: {564, 565, 566} the ticklabels disappear!

Comment: @API: Try revised solution. There was some rounding off issues with the internal representation, so this version only checks up to three digits.

Comment: So there's no way to just... have it not produce intermediates?

Comment: @EgorHans: This was quite some time ago and things have changed a lot. The answer here seems to indicate that those were not duplicated ticks, but just truncated. If you don't like this solutions, I suggest you post a new question and include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, since my comment I figured out that `xtick=data` seems to do the trick (although there is still a weird gap between the data points).

Comment: This adds a weird shift to the tick labels.

Comment: @mcmuffin6o: I suggest you post a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem  you are experiencing.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'll put it on my to-do list, but unfortunately I have a master's thesis to write at the moment