pgfplots: only integer numbers and only ticks at integer places on the x-axis

I want to create xbar-diagrams like this, but I want to set

only integer numbers at the bottom x-axis (no 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, ...)    and
only ticks at the places of integer numbers (no ticks at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, ...)

There is also an other problem: xmax goes  from 1 up to '~400' (with the same diagram width), so it will be not a good idea to set x explicitly, like xtick={1,2,...,\n} (here  \def\n{400}). 
The automatic, adaptive x-axis labeling of pgfplots is OK, but only integers should appear.

I tried from here
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286623/46023
xticklabel={%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\IntegerTick}{\tick}%
        \pgfmathprintnumberto[verbatim,fixed,precision=3]{\tick}\tickAdjusted%
        \pgfmathparse{\IntegerTick == \tickAdjusted ? 1: 0}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax$\IntegerTick$\else\fi%
},  

but this method will still set the ticks (at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 and so on)...

What do I have to do?

\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,6,155,400}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\A{random(0,\n)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\B{random(0,\n-1)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\R{abs(\n-\A-\B)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
width=11cm,% needed 
height=5cm, 
xbar,
bar shift=0pt,
bar width=5mm,
y tick label as interval,
nodes near coords, 
axis x line*=none, % hide upper x-axis
%
ymin=0.5, ymax=4.5,
xmin=0, xmax=\n,
extra x ticks={\n}, % for savety, sometimes he will not set the last....
ytick={1,...,4},
yticklabels={Rest, B, A}, 
title={Diagram No. \n},
title style={anchor=south, yshift=3mm,},
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286623/46023
%xticklabel={%
%        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\IntegerTick}{\tick}%
%        \pgfmathprintnumberto[verbatim,fixed,precision=3]{\tick}\tickAdjusted%
%        \pgfmathparse{\IntegerTick == \tickAdjusted ? 1: 0}%
%        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\relax$\IntegerTick$\else\fi%
%},  
]
\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (\A, 3.5) };
\addplot[fill=brown] coordinates { (\B, 2.5) };
\addplot[fill=gray] coordinates { (\R, 1.5) };
\end{axis}

% 2nd percentual axis ==========================
\begin{axis}[
width=11cm, 
height=5cm, 
axis x line=top, 
hide y axis, 
x axis line style={-},
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}\%},
minor tick num=1,
]
\end{axis}
% ======================================
\end{tikzpicture}
}%% end foreach %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}


maybe like this ?

You set xtick explicitly to have ticks only at integers within your specified range.
Remove conditional xticklabel code since you explicitly define xtick positions.


\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,6}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\A{random(0,\n)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\B{random(0,\n-1)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\R{abs(\n-\A-\B)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
width=11cm,% needed 
height=5cm, 
xbar,
bar shift=0pt,
bar width=5mm,
y tick label as interval,
nodes near coords, 
axis x line*=none, % hide upper x-axis
%
ymin=0.5, ymax=4.5,
xmin=0, xmax=\n,
xtick={0,...,\n}, % Set ticks only at integer positions
ytick={1,...,4},
yticklabels={Rest, B, A}, 
title={Diagram No. \n},
title style={anchor=south, yshift=3mm,},
]
\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (\A, 3.5) };
\addplot[fill=brown] coordinates { (\B, 2.5) };
\addplot[fill=gray] coordinates { (\R, 1.5) };
\end{axis}

% 2nd percentual axis ==========================
\begin{axis}[
width=11cm, 
height=5cm, 
axis x line=top, 
hide y axis, 
x axis line style={-},
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}\%},
minor tick num=1,
]
\end{axis}
% ======================================
\end{tikzpicture}
}%% end foreach %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}

Edit 1 to take into account xmax =400

\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,6}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\A{random(0,\n)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\B{random(0,\n-1)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\R{abs(\n-\A-\B)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
width=11cm,% needed 
height=5cm, 
xbar,
bar shift=0pt,
bar width=5mm,
y tick label as interval,
nodes near coords, 
axis x line*=none, % hide upper x-axis
%
ymin=0.5, ymax=4.5,
xmin=0, xmax=400, % <= Adjusted here
xtick distance=40, % Set ticks at every 40 units
ytick={1,...,4},
yticklabels={Rest, B, A}, 
title={Diagram No. \n},
title style={anchor=south, yshift=3mm,},
]
\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (\A, 3.5) };
\addplot[fill=brown] coordinates { (\B, 2.5) };
\addplot[fill=gray] coordinates { (\R, 1.5) };
\end{axis}

% 2nd percentual axis ==========================
\begin{axis}[
width=11cm, 
height=5cm, 
axis x line=top, 
hide y axis, 
x axis line style={-},
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}\%},
minor tick num=1,
]
\end{axis}
% ======================================
\end{tikzpicture}
}%% end foreach %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}


I am sorry, I did not explain good: xmax goes up to '~400', so it will be not a good idea to set x explicitly, like xticks={1,2,...,\n} (here  \def\n{400}).

you coudl use xmax=400, xtick distance=40,

xmax goes from 1 to 400. I don't know what is the general x distance calculation method.

I edit my code this way.

OK, I can probably work with the xtick distance=<*> key.
